# During a FTP upload, the total size of the file is send?

Tags: ftp

When you send a file by HTTP, web browsers send the total file size in the http header.

Do you think it's the same with the FTP protocole?

Martin

Answer (score 5):

FTP has a number of transfer modes, but none of them send the entire length of the file beforehand. You can see them all in [RFC 959](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc959.html), section 3.4.

Note that the SIZE command defined in [RFC 3659](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3659#section-4.1) is purely for downloads, not uploads.

Answer (score 0):

No, an FTP file transfer is treated as a stream of bytes that ends when the connection is closed normally.  There is a new "SIZE" command for FTP defined in RFC3659, but this is a fairly recent addition that I would guess isn't seeing a lot of use.