# How to process uploaded files immediately as they finish uploading

Tags: upload, message-queue

I have a system which takes user-uploaded files and processes them in a particular way. The only thing I'm asking about here is the timing -- how can I get the files processed *immediately* after they are done being uploaded?

I have used queuing systems in the past -- beanstalkd, for example, and I'm pretty sure a work queue should be part of this solution, but I'm stuck on the notification part. The problem is that the upload itself is not connected to the processing. Upload is handled by an SFTP service. Processing is handled by a set of perl scripts.

How can I alert the job queue that an upload is finished?

I've considered the following ideas, but they all seem hackish, fragile, or untenable in some way.

- Somehow send a checksum to the job queue so that it will know a file is complete. I couldn't think of a good way to do this, though, as the thing that does this would probably also know that the upload is done anyway, and ought to just alert the queue directly.
- Make sure files uploaded use their checksum as their name. That won't work because we are dealing with users doing the actual upload.
- Have users send a second file, "complete", after uploading, and poll for that file. Once again, too complicated for users.
- Watch the growth of the file -- if the file stops growing for an extended period, consider it complete. This is not reliable, though.

In case it matters, the architecture is

- Jscape SFTP server
- Perl
- Linux (Ubuntu 10.04) OS

**edit 2012-11-06**

I did a bit more research and found this:

- Stack Overflow: [How to determine wheter a file is still being transferred via ftp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7241978/how-to-determine-wheter-a-file-is-still-being-transferred-via-ftp)

and this:

- Some web dev forum post (old, ca 2004): http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t136270-determing-if-ftp-process-is-finished.html

(among other things, all similar). Long story short, the answer is "**You have to signal, in some way, that the upload is finished; all other tests for finished-ness are unreliable**".

It turns out that my SFTP server does have a trigger system that can fire off actions, including arbitrary processes, in response to events such as "file upload is complete". So I'm going to use that. I am still curious if anyone has found a more general-purpose solution, but I'm going to close this one since I think the question is answered.

Comment: How do users upload the files? Are they using a web-form, with a file upload box? And is that POST attached to a Perl script or some other script? If so, you can add in your "perl [location to perl script]" after the file is uploaded to your Temp directory.

Comment: No, not a web form. Strictly SFTP, via whatever SFTP client they wish.