# PHP how to check if file finished uploading

Tags: php, file, file-upload, nginx, amazon-s3

I'm running php on Nginx and users are uploading files to my server using my app.

I need to write a process that will check if files have finished uploading and then move them to Amazon S3 bucket.

My questions are:

1. How to check if files finished uploading?
2. Will it be faster to upload it directly to S3?

Comment: The first question is normally done with code (and it depends on the code so you need to share it) and the second question depends on the network and server infrastructure so you need to metric that and then show the metrics (which would already tell you which one is faster, however they would also enable anyone here to tell you as well). Only knowing about the software you use for hosting (Nginx) or the serverice for hosting (Amazon S3) is far to little information to say actually anything.

Comment: Well then, set aside the networking, the code part for checking if the file was uploaded - i need to write it and my question is how would I know if the file finished uploading...  Keep size in DB? Is there another Linux way to check?

Comment: I have problems to follow you with removing even these little things, perhaps you're looking for *File System Related Functions*?. Also PHP has a feature called *File Uploads* you might be interested as well - http://php.net/manual

Comment: I think i found it... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7241978/how-to-determine-wheter-a-file-is-still-being-transferred-via-ftp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is **always** faster to cut out the middle-man and upload directly to S3.